# C++ overloading conflict on exact template argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, overloading

`bar` defined below allows two kinds of initalizations(the template of `bar` will always be several `int`s in use)

```
template<class C>
inline void store(C dst) {}
template<class T, class C, class... E>
inline void store(C dst, T val, E... etc) {
    *dst = val;
    store(++dst, etc...);
}
template<class... T>
class bar {
    static const int n = sizeof...(T);
    int data[n];
public:
    bar(int x) {for(int i=0; i<n; i++) data[i]=x;}
    bar(T... x) {store(data,x...);}
};
```

It looks fine; however if the template is exactly **one** `int`, this code is ambigious to compiler(though both understanding have same meaning):

```
bar<int> s(3);
```

Is the only way to avoid this to specialization the one `int` case? (That anyway makes the code more complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the variadic constructor when there's just one argument and is an `int`.

If you have c++17 you can do it like

```
template <
    std::size_t N = sizeof...(T),
    std::enable_if_t<(N != 1 || !(std::is_same_v<T, int> && ...)), bool> = true>
bar(T... x) {store(data,x...);}
```

Otherwise, you can go along with:

```
template <bool... Pred>
struct all_dummy;

template <bool... Preds>
using all = std::is_same<all_dummy<Preds...>, all_dummy<((void)Preds, true)...>>;

template <
    std::size_t N = sizeof...(T),
    std::enable_if_t<(N != 1 || !all<std::is_same<T, int>::value...>::value), bool> = true
>
bar(T... x) {store(data,x...);}
```

Comment: Sorry but... shouldn't be disabled when `T` is `int`? I mean... shouldn't be `std::enable_if_t<(N != 1) || ((false == std::is_same_v<T, int>) || ...), bool> = true` or something similar?

Comment: Now I'm agree. But (1) `N == 1` seems superfluous to me (if `N != 1` the condition is true thanks the preceding `N != 1`) and (2) there isn't a real difference (because `sizeof...(T) == 1`) but it seems to me that should be `((!std::is_same_v<T, int>) || ...)` instead of `((!std::is_same_v<T, int>) && ...)`; I mean: the condition should be true also when only a type is different from `int`, not only when all types are different to `int` (but, I repeat: with `N == 1` there shouldn't be a real difference)

Comment: @max66 - Yes, I realized that and removed it.

Answer (score 1):

What about transforming the second constructor in a template one and SFINAE enable it only when `T...` isn't `int` ?

I mean something as

```
template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(T),
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
             (N != 1u)
             || (false == std::is_same<std::tuple<int, T...>,
                                       std::tuple<T..., int>>{})>>
bar(T... x) {store(data,x...);}
```

Obviously, if you can use only C++11, you have to use `typename std::enable_if<>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<>`.

If you can use C++17, you can use template folding, to check that `T...` isn't `int`, as suggested by Jans.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the only way to avoid this to specialization the one int case?

No as shown with other answer with SFINAE.

C++20 would even allow nicer syntax with `requires`:

```
template <class... Ts>
class bar {
    static const int n = sizeof...(Ts);
    int data[n];
public:
    bar(int x) { std::fill(std::begin(data), std::end(data), x);}
    bar(Ts... xs) requires (n != 1) : data{xs...} {}
};
```

> (That anyway makes the code more complex)

Not really agree compared to SFINAE, with specialization, it might be:

```
template <class... Ts>
class bar_impl
{
protected:
    static const int n = sizeof...(Ts);
    int data[n];
public:
    bar(Ts... xs) : data{xs...} {}
};

template <>
class bar_impl<int> {
    static const int n = 1;
    int data[n];
};

template <class... Ts>
class bar : bar_impl<Ts...> {
public:
    using bar_impl<Ts...>::bar_impl;

    bar(int x) { std::fill(std::begin(data), std::end(data), x);}
    // ...
};
```